# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 but lipo -info shows ok

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I think you guys have seen this kind of errors before, but mine is special.

I have a few static libs in my Xcode project, when I tried to build it I got this error. But I have checked all my libs with command `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info $libname`, it gave me `Architectures in the fat file: /Users/kiwi/Documents/Development/SourceCode/prj/lib.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64`.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_SSLv2_server_method",
>   referenced from:
>         CSSLctx::Create(bool, CSSLctx::sslProtocol) in libudp.a(SSLStream.o)   "_SSLv2_client_method", referenced from:
>         CSSLctx::Create(bool, CSSLctx::sslProtocol) in libudp.a(SSLStream.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: _SSLv2_server_method should be from openssl. Are you linking with libcrypto and libssl ?

Comment: yes, i have linked libcrypto and libssl

Comment: I think I just found the reason. the same code of my libraries works fine with iOS8.1 SDK(XCode 6). but mine is iOS9.3 SDK(XCode 7), something is wrong with the compiler. still don't know how to fix it. :(